# (Linguagem R) Como deixar os eixos dos gráficos mais detalhados no ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, r

[image: Plot em questão]

Gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar mais números ao meu eixo y, para que a grade do fundo fique com mais linhas horizontais. Reparem que no meu gráfico, o eixo Y só apresenta as marcações a cada quinhentas unidades(0, 500, 1000 e 1500). Gostaria que tivessem mais, de cem em cem por exemplo, tendo as marcações de 0, 100, 200, 300 etc

```
    ggplot(data = engrep,
       colours(Curso),
       mapping = aes(x = Ano,
                     y = Reprovações,
                     group = Curso,
                     Col = Curso,
                     label = Reprovações,
                     colour = Curso)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab('Ano') +
  ylab('Reprovações') +
  ggtitle('Número de Reprovações Anuais Nos Cursos de Engenharia - UFCG')
```

A seguir um dput dos meus dados correspondentes aos dois primeiros ano (2002 e 2003)

```
    structure(list(Curso = structure(c(17L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 25L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 21L, 24L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 25L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 21L, 24L), .Label = c("ADMINISTRAÇÃO", 
"AGRONOMIA", "ARQUITETURA E URBANISMO", "ARTE E MÍDIA", "CIÊNCIA DA COMPUTAÇÃO", 
"CIÊNCIAS", "CIÊNCIAS BIOLÓGICAS", "CIÊNCIAS CONTÁBEIS", 
"CIÊNCIAS ECONÔMICAS", "CIÊNCIAS SOCIAIS", "COMUNICAÇÃO SOCIAL", 
"DESENHO INDUSTRIAL", "DESIGN", "DIREITO", "ENFERMAGEM", "ENG. DE BIOTECNOLOGIA E BIOPROCESSOS", 
"ENGENHARIA AGRÍCOLA", "ENGENHARIA AMBIENTAL", "ENGENHARIA CIVIL", 
"ENGENHARIA DE ALIMENTOS", "ENGENHARIA DE BIOSSISTEMAS", "ENGENHARIA DE MATERIAIS", 
"ENGENHARIA DE MINAS", "ENGENHARIA DE PETRÓLEO", "ENGENHARIA DE PRODUÇÃO", 
"ENGENHARIA ELÉTRICA", "ENGENHARIA FLORESTAL", "ENGENHARIA MECÂNICA", 
"ENGENHARIA QUÍMICA", "ESTATÍSTICA", "FARMÁCIA", "FILOSOFIA", 
"FÍSICA", "GEOGRAFIA", "HISTÓRIA", "INTERDISCIPLINAR EM EDUC. DO CAMPO", 
"LETRAS", "LICENCIATURA INTERCULTURAL INDÍGENA", "MATEMÁTICA", 
"MEDICINA", "MEDICINA VETERINÁRIA", "METEOROLOGIA", "MÚSICA", 
"NUTRIÇÃO", "ODONTOLOGIA", "PEDAGOGIA", "PSICOLOGIA", "QUÍMICA", 
"SERVIÇO SOCIAL", "TECNOLOGIA EM AGROECOLOGIA", "TECNOLOGIA EM GESTÃO PÚBLICA", 
"TECNOLOGIA QUÍMICA (COUROS E TANANTES)"), class = "factor"), 
    Ano = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", 
    "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
    "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), 
    Reprovações = c(160L, 529L, 288L, 108L, 608L, 72L, 502L, 
    182L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 170L, 532L, 219L, 122L, 757L, 
    60L, 473L, 178L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os valores que serão apresentados no gráfico são controlados pelo `scale_y_continuous`, basta adicionar

```
+   scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, max(engrep$Reprovações, na.rm = T)+50, 100)))
```

no final do código que você vai ter o que deseja. O `breaks` delimita as linhas horizontais no gráfico, o `label` vai ser o mesmo que os valores do `breaks`. Se você preferir, também pode colocar outro `label` (de mesmo comprimento dos `breaks`, mas não faz sentido).